# Problemas com URLs no Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Caros,

Estou com o seguinte erro meu projeto:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf
'api.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see
valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a
circular import.
```

Este projeto funcionava corretamente, porém tive que formatar minha máquina. Após baixar novamente os arquivos do meu git, começou a dar este problema.

Segue minha api.url:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from ChatBot.views import UserViewSet
from ChatBot.views import GroupViewSet
from django.conf.urls import url

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', GroupViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('ChatBot.urls')),
]
```

Minha ChatBot.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^resultado/$', views.ClassRankingView.as_view(), name='resultado'),
    url(r'^learning/$', views.WordEmbeddingCalculation.as_view(), name='learning'),
    url(r'^weight/$', views.NovaViewTeste.as_view(), name='weight'),
]
```

O erro completo:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/willian/ChatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/willian/ChatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/willian/ChatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/willian/ChatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/willian/ChatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/willian/ChatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/willian/ChatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/home/willian/ChatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/home/willian/ChatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/willian/ChatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'api.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Este mesmo código, funciona em outras máquinas, porém na minha não. Saberiam me dizer o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Você cita `api.url` e `api.urls` em diferentes momentos. Não seria apenas um erro de digitação/nomenclatura?

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from ChatBot.views import UserViewSet
from ChatBot.views import GroupViewSet
#from django.conf.urls import url

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', GroupViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('router.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('ChatBot.urls', namespace='chatbot')),
]
```

ChatBot.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


app_name = 'chatbot'


urlpatterns = [
    path('resultado/', views.ClassRankingView.as_view(), name='resultado'),
    path('learning/', views.WordEmbeddingCalculation.as_view(), name='learning'),
    path('weight/', views.NovaViewTeste.as_view(), name='weight'),
]
```

Creio que usando path resolva o problema e o "namespace" poderá auxiliar ao referenciar as urls no template, por exemplo, você poderá referenciar a url "weight" utilizando {% url 'chatbot:weight' %}.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda. Testei o que tu mandou, porém continua dando o erro. O que eu fiz para resolver, foi limpar minhas urls e tirar as que não estava utilizando, deixando apenas as que iram realmente ser utilizadas. E mesmo assim, algumas vezes ainda ocorre o erro. Devo ter configurado algo errado em minha máquina.